# Why does this code go into infinite while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, boolean

The following code goes into infinite loop when in fact if I do step by step, it should terminate when the value of `i` becomes 0 at which point `while` condition becomes `False`. Thereby, the `while` loop should terminate. Based on my understanding, the output should have been `-5 -4 -3 -2  -1  0` since `0` is `False` which makes `while True` condition `False`. Can somebody please explain why the code does not terminate and goes into infinite loop?

```
i = -5        # initialization
while True:   # condition
    print(i)  # statement
    i += 1

print("exit")
```

Comment: The `while` condition is `True`, not an expression whose value depends on `i`. When do you think the value `True` ceases to be true?

Comment: You want `while i` (or more explicitly and clearly, `while i != 0`).

Comment: True is always true. True never "becomes false".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter what the value of `i` is; your loop only considers the value of `True`, which is a constant that never becomes false.

```
i = -5
while i != 0:  # i alone works, but this is clearer
  print(i)
  i += 1
```

Comment: thank you for answering. I thought `0` always translates to `False` in boolean and any other value translates to `True`.

Comment: It does, but nowhere do you have a value of 0 (from any source) being used in your loop condition.

Comment: Suppose you had two variables `i` and `j`, one zero and one non-zero. Would you expect your loop to know which one was "supposed" to be the loop condition?

Comment: that's right. One last clarification request, the integer range in Python is -2147483648 through 2147483647   If I initialize ` i = 2147483647` then would your code print negative numbers till zero? I tried doing so using your corrected code  but the code does not go to the negative integer range instead goes on printing the positive numbers `2147483648,2147483649,.......,2149456699.......` and so on.

Comment: There is no "integer range" in Python. The size of an integer is limited only by the available memory on your machine. `x + 1 > x` is true for any `x` with type `int`.

Comment: You can adjust the condition to be `while i < 0` if you are not sure what the initial sign of `i` is.